# VB.NET Execute a looping query and display its result in 1 datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an Excel sheet loaded in `dt_data` and I want to compare the values of `dt_data` to my database and display it on another datagridview which is `dt_sample`. Inside my database there is past 3 months record and I want to get them all to be displayed here is my code below:

```
Try

            For i As Integer = 0 To dt_data.RowCount - 3
                Dim meter_number As String
                meter_number = dt_data.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                Dim query As String = "Select * from customer where meter_num = @meter_num"
                conn.Open()
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meter_num", meter_number)
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                Dim ds As New DataSet


                If i = dt_data.RowCount - 3 Then
                    da.Fill(ds, "customer")
                    dt_sample.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                End If



                conn.Close()

            Next
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
            'End Try
            'Catch ex As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWdpU.png

Comment: Please include your results as formatted text within the question, not as an external image.

Comment: *"I want to compare the values"*.  How do you want to compare them?  We shouldn't have to guess this stuff.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i want to compare them by a click of a button, i have a button for loading from excel to datagridview which is named dt_data and when i click another button it should compare the particular column from dt_data to my sql server database

Comment: COMPARE THEM HOW?  For equality?  For relative value?  For something else?  Then do what with the results?  Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: For knowing the consumption for the past 3 months and getting it's average

Answer (score 0):

```
Using command As New SqlCommand()
                command.Connection = conn

                Dim parameterNames As New List(Of String)(dt_data.RowCount - 2)
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt_data.RowCount - 3
                    Dim parameterName As String = "@meter_num_" & i
                    Dim meter_number As String = dt_data.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, meter_number)
                    parameterNames.Add(parameterName)
                Next

                command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cycle = @cycle and meter_num IN ({0})", String.Join(",", parameterNames), ("ORDER BY Client_Name ASC"))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cycle", cycle2last)

                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "customer")
                Compare_Reading.dt_last2month.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            End Using
```

that's what i found solution and it successfully meet my problems